# Angular 5: Cannot read property 'USERID' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-forms

**Hi everyone,**

Please help me find my bug, I create a Form Register with register model.
My english is poor, So i show images for my Problem. Thanks All !!!

My model:
[image]
Component:
[image]
HTML
[image]
And bug:
[image]

Comment: Please do not include code as images.

Comment: My bad, sorry. I will draw experience for the next time.

Comment: did the answer help you

Answer (score 3):

You need at least an empty Object of RegisterUser before setting the [(ngModel)]. Otherwise modelreg will be undefined.

```
modelreg : RegisterUser = New RegisterUser();
```

and the corresponding template should be,

```
<input [(ngModel)]="RegisteredUser.USERID">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got a number of things wrong .Firstly , NgModel is producing the as the moment the component gets loaded the value of USERID is not defined, so therefore you need to assign the value of USERID to empty string.
Secondly, the ngModel should be modelreg.USERID not RegisteredUser.USERID

Answer (score 0):

try to create a empty object using this syntax:

```
modelreg = {} as RegisterUser;
```

and corresponding template should be:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="modelreg.USERID">
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RegisteredUser?.USERID
```

add the question mark before . so it will not continue when RegisteredUser is null. only works in html file

or

```
[(ngModel)]="modelreg && modelreg.USERID ? modelreg.USERID : ''"
```

this should applicable for all the properties of modelreg those accessed from html

or another good approach will be setting default values in class

```
export class RegsteredUser{
USERID : strng = "";
FIRST_NAME: strng = "";
.....
}
```

in component instead

```
registeredUser : Registeredser
```

try

```
registeredUser = new Registeredser()
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to read `USERID` from a TYPE attribute that does not exist at runtime. Thus the cannot read from undefined error.

Try this instead in your `input`

`[(ngModel)]="modelReg.USERID"`